# install gphoto2 without libgphoto

Tags: gphoto2

I've been trying to install gphoto 2-2.5.20 and libgphoto2-2.5.22 but whenever i install gphoto it uses the older libgphoto2-2.5.12 which dosn't work with my camera(Olympus E-M1 Mark II) . Is there any good tutorial out there how to install everything properly ? cant find anything

Thanks for answers

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

According to [NEWS file of `libgphoto2`](https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2/blob/14e7595230c303254218d7e5eeb98068d5678995/NEWS#L72) the support for your camera was added in version 2.5.19.

For Ubuntu this means that you [need to have](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgphoto2-6&searchon=names) Ubuntu 18.10 (*cosmic*) or future 19.04 (*disco*). Both versions are non LTS.

So on Ubuntu LTS you need to compile `gphoto2` and `libgphoto2` by yourself.
Below is the method for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

1. Enable *Source Code* repositories from Sofware & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. Install build tools and build dependencies for gphoto packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential git devscripts
   sudo apt-get build-dep libgphoto2-dev gphoto2
   ```
3. Clone source code from Debian (we will get version 2.5.20-3 for both gphoto2 and libphoto2 for compatibility):

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://salsa.debian.org/debian-phototools-team/libgphoto2.git -b debian/2.5.20-3
   cd libgphoto2
   rm debian/source/format # disable 3.0 (quilt) format
   dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
   sudo apt-get install ../libgphoto2*.deb

   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://salsa.debian.org/debian-phototools-team/gphoto2.git -b debian/2.5.20-3
   cd gphoto2
   rm debian/source/format # disable 3.0 (quilt) format
   dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
   sudo apt-get install ../gphoto2*.deb
   ```
4. Check that gphoto packages were installed (compare with output below):

   > ```
   > $ dpkg -l | grep gphoto
   > ii  gphoto2                     2.5.20-3         amd64        digital camera command-line client
   > ii  libgphoto2-6:amd64          2.5.20-3         amd64        gphoto2 digital camera library
   > ii  libgphoto2-dev:amd64        2.5.20-3         amd64        gphoto2 digital camera library (development files)
   > ii  libgphoto2-dev-doc          2.5.20-3         all          gphoto2 digital camera library (development documentation)
   > ii  libgphoto2-l10n             2.5.20-3         all          gphoto2 digital camera library - localized messages
   > ii  libgphoto2-port12:amd64     2.5.20-3         amd64        gphoto2 digital camera port library
   >
   > $ gphoto2 --version
   > gphoto2 2.5.20
   >
   > Copyright (c) 2000-2018 Lutz Mueller and others
   >
   > gphoto2 comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. You may
   > redistribute copies of gphoto2 under the terms of the GNU General Public
   > License. For more information about these matters, see the files named COPYING.
   >
   > This version of gphoto2 is using the following software versions and options:
   > gphoto2         2.5.20         gcc, popt(m), exif, cdk, aa, jpeg, readline
   > libgphoto2      2.5.20         all camlibs, gcc, ltdl, EXIF
   > libgphoto2_port 0.12.0         iolibs: disk ptpip serial usb1 usbdiskdirect usbscsi, gcc, ltdl, USB, serial without locking
   > ```

I do not have any DSLR for test, but I hope this method will work.

---

Also note that many GUI applications use gphoto2 library as back-end to communicate the camera. You can try [digiKam](https://www.digikam.org/), [DarkTable](https://www.darktable.org/), [Entangle](https://entangle-photo.org/). All they have packages in official Ubuntu repositories.