# compiling ffmpeg on 18.04.2 fails with --enable-lib* not found

Tags: compiling, ffmpeg

using the official guides I already succesfully compiled ffmpeg (with decklink support) on a SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1.

As the resulting binaries do not work on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 I tried to compile again, using the same guide. I also updated Ubuntu before and the dependencies should all be up to date. Also, folder structure seems OK.

So it actually fails during ffmpeg ./configure, shell spitting out for example:

```
./ffmpegcompil.sh: 21: ./ffmpegcompil.sh: --enable-libass: not found
```

config.log does not make me much smarter, it just seems to fail in testing phase, starting with

`...
zscale_filter='yes'
mktemp -u XXXXXX
uxtubn
test_ld cc
test_cc
...`

After that, many tests, a few warnings, less errors, then abort without notice in the config.log.

If i remove --enable-libass from the script it will fail with another lib "not found".

How to troubleshoot this?
THX!

HERE´S MY SCRIPT:

`cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
cd ffmpeg && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libsrt \
  --enable-decklink \
--extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include/decklink" \
--extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include/decklink" \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install && \
hash -r`

Comment: Show your script.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the power of APT to get build dependencies for the package:

1. Enable *Source code* repositories in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. Install build-dependencies for ffmpeg:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg
   ```
3. Proceed with configuring and compilation.

Note: the ffmpeg is [already packaged on all Ubuntu versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ffmpeg) with wide set of plugins.

Comment: well- I uncommented all the deb-src lines in the sources.list, ran `sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg`, then config/compile script again. No changes. Not sure though the dependencies came down allright. How could I check?

Comment: I do not know how your script works. Usually sources for Debian and Ubuntu are hosted on Salsa. [FFmpeg from it](https://salsa.debian.org/multimedia-team/ffmpeg) must compile if it is not too new for current Ubuntu release (use correct tags/branches).

Comment: I was just following this guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu and the included script which uses this source: https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 So you´d recommend just using the mentioned source instead of the standard one?

Comment: Yes, I recommend to use source code from Salsa. You may want to use my other answer [as reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/1120346/66509).

Answer (score 0):

guess what the problem was:
I hashed out some of the options in the script (can´t see that above for formatting reasons) which caused the following options not being digested by the configure script. "--enable-libass not found" just meaning it started anew from there on.

What´s the learning from this? No hashes in between command options?